# Как сделать AudioCD из FLAC+CUE под Linux?

Tags: linux, cd

Имеется пара flac+cue. Cue в Win1251. Локаль ru_RU.UTF-8.

Чем из этого сделать правильный AudioCD? Предпочтительно с командной строки.

Дистрибутив, если это важно, — Debian Stretch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Процесс:

1. Пилим исходный flac на треки.
2. Декодируем полученные флаки в вавы.
3. Пишем вавы на диск.

Команды:

1. `shnsplit -f file.cue -t %n-%t -o flac file.flac`
2. `for i in [01][0-9]-*.flac; do flac -d $i; done`
3. `wodim -audio *.wav`

Можно в другом порядке:

1. Декодируем flac в wav.
2. Пилим результирующий вав на треки.
3. Пишем диск.

Команды:

1. `flac -d file.flac`
2. `shnsplit -f file.cue file.wav`
3. `wodim -audio split-track*.wav`